# Programmatically join 2 videos

Tags: video

hi how to join 2 videos those are in **different format(avi,mpeg,..), fps(frames per second),resolution** . i'm trying to append my logo video to all uploaded videos. Moreover i'm using ubuntu os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy file1.mpg file2.avi -o output.avi
```

Comment: Oh well :-(. I suspect there is an incantation there somewhere but I'm not near a suitable machine at the mo.